# Seeing if a hard coded value in a set is part of a Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of hard coded values that I need to check against a Select.

If I do a Select with a "not in" or "in" the set of values it provides the inverse of what I need.

```
SELECT  * FROM TABLE
WHERE FIELD_NAME is in ('Value1', 'Value2'...)
```

I need the opposite of the above statement.  SELECT-ing from the hard coded values to see what is and is not in the SELECT from the table.

Comment: SQL Server.   Just tagged it.

Comment: Any null values involved? If that's the case, the NOT IN result may surprise you.

Comment: No nulls in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In standard ANSI SQL you can use a `values` clause:

```
select v.*
from (
  values ('value1'),('value2'),('value3')
) as v(val)
where v.val not in (select some_column
                    from some_table);
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . SQL Server supports this as well.